# Retrieve Data sent to requestbin.fullcontact.com using GET request

Tags: post, server, get, request

I have used the POST method of Python's Request library and sent the data to that URL. Below given is the python code to send data to through that URL:

```
import requests, time
r = requests.post('https://requestbin.fullcontact.com/1ntxskn1', 
data={"ts":time.time()})
print(r.status_code)
print(r.content)
```

And the Data which is sent is displayed in this way, See title 'RAW body' in the bottom:
[image: Image is taken from the requestbin]

I'm not sure whether the data is stored somewhere to make the GET request or not

**I'm ready to use any language or method for the GET request!!**

Question: *How can I retrieve the data using a GET request?*

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to write a simple api controller and get the request directly to your app, instead of using something like fullcontact.

If the purpose is to test your api on local debug, you can use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to tunnel the request to your local environment.
Or if you want to test specific request, you can copy the request content from fullcontact to [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/)